# Does it makes sense to have the operational DB and analytics DB on the same SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, etl

Let's say I have a single table that stores tracing information from mobile devices (each record has deviceID, transaction info, a json column with full details about the operation, time of operation, user, etc...), this is the operational DB.
Some users may need to get get tracing information of a time range, about a certain user or device. So a simple select with filters, it won't impact the data insert.

Some other users will need to do larger analytics operations, aggregations over months of collected data. I read that this analysis process should be done on an analytics DB, for not to impact the operational DB.

But I have one limit, only one SQLServer instance available.

So I should write an ETL that does a periodic batch copy of the data on a new DB, with the same single table with some more indexes and without the json column (to save space, because for the kind of analysis we need is useless)

Now my question is, given that we are talking of an operational table and and analysis table (more than of an operational DB and an analysis DB), and at my client premises I will only have a single instance of SQLServer, does it make sense to keep both tables inside the same DB in the same SQLServer instance? Do I have improved performances over using a single table for both operational and analytics queries?
Saying in a different way, I have two options, using one SQLServer instance:

1. insert data on one table with all the indexes I need, and query that table for tracing AND for analytics
2. insert data on one table with few indexes, and copy it to another table with more indexes and a reduced overall size, and query the first for tracing and the second for analytics

If you tell me that if I put everything on the same SQLServer, 1 and 2 won't be much different in terms of performance, I'll stick to 1 because it's easier.

If I do a few minutes long aggregations on the analytics table, will writing on operational table will be slowed down less or the same of doing the analysis directly on the operational table?

Thanks

Comment: This question is really hard to answer. You did not provide information about utilization. Do you have 1-10 users performing updates and inserts concurrently or 2 million? Can you add an approximation of how the data will be accessed and updated? If concurrency against an OLTP DB is becomes an issue, then an OLAP database may not be a bad idea.

Comment: Hard to say without details but if you have only one SQL Instance, it's unlikely to be worth the extra effort of copying into a different table elsewhere _unless_ you can do that in batch overnight and have an out of date table to report off the next day. Depending on current utilisation etc. , I suggest just getting the indexing right, and perhaps try out snapshot isolation to help with concurrency if required (which has it's own I/O cost). First thing you should really do is try it and assess the performance and identify bottlenecks.

Comment: @RossBush I will have 500 users doing something between 1000 and 5000 inserts a day, data won't be updated, will only be read a few times a day for tracing by a few users.
Then supposedly will be read for copying to the other table, that still will never have updates, but reads for aggregations.
I've read about OLAP, but it doesn't really suit my needs.

Comment: @Nick.Mc yes I understand I should assess the performance, but if I go with the easy solution (and it will work, of course, we're not talking about huge amounts of data), how do I know if the other solution would perform better, without testing it as well. 
I'm just trying to do things the best way, and I'm reading that operational and analytics should be separate, but never found an article explaining how much separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Saying in a different way, I have two options, using one SQLServer instance:
>
> 1. insert data on one table with all the indexes I need, and query that table for tracing AND for analytics
> 2. insert data on one table with few indexes, and copy it to another table with more indexes and a reduced overall size, and query the first for tracing and the second for analytics

As already mentioned in the comments, the answer on which implementation would perform better for you will depend on the specific use cases and read to write ratio of the table within your database, as well as the general overall resource contention.

### Option 2

If there's a lot of **concurrent** reads and writes to the table, then it's possible for them to lock and block each other (with the default isolation level in SQL Server). Having a second instance of the table that decouples (if possible) the overlap of reading and writing use cases, can improve performance in regards to locking, in such a scenario. Typically it's good to isolate the second instance to a separate server to decouple the resource contention as well, but as you've noted, that's not possible in your case.

But writing the same data twice doesn't come free. And again, being on the same server will utilize double the resources it previously would've had you only kept things to a single table. And to maximize the benefit of decoupling the read and write use cases, you'd likely want to write the data in batches, at a time that's offset from when the read use cases occur. This would leave your copy of the table stale as opposed to being in real-time sync with the original table. There's also extra maintenance to keep the structure of the table in sync as schema changes occur on the original. It's not a simple task.

### Option 1

Conversely, if you don't have a lot of concurrent reads and writes, or if there is a lot of concurrency, but not a lot of querying and resource contention overall, then a single instance of the table, indexed appropriately for most of your main use cases, could be just fine. The locking time could be milliseconds to as little as nanoseconds, immeasurable as far as your application is concerned.

### Option 0

Aside from all of that, a third alternative option is to change the database isolation level to something more conducive to optimistic concurrency. In SQL Server, the options for that are [Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI) and just Snapshot Isolation](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/). In a nutshell, optimistic concurrency generally allows read and write queries to operate on the same table concurrently without blocking each other. Readers don't block writers, and writers don't block readers. (Writers will still block other writers.) This works because a version store maintains each version of an actively changing record in the table. When a write query is currently making a change to a row, it's previous version is available to be read from until that write change is committed and the lock on it is released.

Both options for optimistic concurrency isolation levels have [different pros and cons](https://littlekendra.com/2016/02/18/how-to-choose-rcsi-snapshot-isolation-levels/) (as discussed in the linked articles) but I prefer RCSI which globally enables optimistic concurrency on the server. This is akin to how Azure SQL Database and a few other modern database systems work out of the box. And to turn it on is essentially flipping the switch on a property of the database with a single line of code.

Comment: There's a continuos write to the table (operational DB), never an update, and a few times during the day some reads (that doesn't worry me).
500 device (but may grow) writing 1000/5000 records per day (but may grow)

Comment: Then there are a few times a week some long queries (minutes) over 40/50 millions records acquired over months.
I already have this system operative, and I'm trying to improve it, and understanding if it's worth it to separate operational and analytics but keep data on the same server.
I also would like to do some continuous analysis on the last 1/2/3 days data, but for this I'll probably use a memory table.

Comment: I add that by reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/get-started-with-columnstore-for-real-time-operational-analytics?view=sql-server-ver16 it seems more or less what I want to do, copy the data for analytics on the same DB. I understand the complexity of doing it myself but this gives me the possibility to remove part of the record data that is useless for analytics and do some transformation.

Comment: @MattiaDurli So a couple things: 1. if you're only inserting and never updating data, then reads won't block writes unless the locks escalate to the Page or Table level. 2. It sounds like you don't do a ton of reads against the table, so the concurrency is somewhat low, but the analytical queries taking minutes long can theoretically lock your table for that long keeping the inserts waiting for a few minutes. If this is not tolerable, then you'll need to do something. 3. Speaking of the analytical queries, 50 million rows isn't that big, so it shouldn't take minutes to process when...

Comment: ... architected properly. You likely need index and query tuning to improve that. A proper columnstore index (as you've found the docs on) typically works amazing for analytical queries and could potentially improve that runtime to a few seconds or less. 4. It's better when you don't have to re-invent the wheel for a number of reasons, some of which I mentioned already, such as additional maintenance and other performance overhead. There's even a number of out-of-the-box features that could automate copying the data to another database for you (Replication, SSIS, AlwaysOn AGs, etc) but are...

Comment: ...likely overkill for your use case. Why not just enable optimistic concurrency on the database (like my answer suggests) and be done with it? You may not even need to go that far with proper query and index tuning (again a columnstore index for analytics). The only actual case I can see being made for wanting to persist the data in two places is if you had a ton of transformations you wanted to persist, that also couldn't be as efficiently handled at runtime even with proper index and query tuning. I say all this having worked with tables in the 10s of billions of rows with high concurrency.

Comment: "*I also would like to do some continuous analysis on the last 1/2/3 days data, but for this I'll probably use a memory table.*" - You probably don't need an In-Memory table for this, especially with the proper indexes. There's a lot of limitations and some gotchas with In-Memory tables, and since SQL Server uses a caching scheme to keep regular table data in Memory automatically anyway, the In-Memory table feature is rarely needed or used.

Comment: Ok, you convinced me to try columnstore indexes and optimistic concurrency before anything else, thanks. 
Two more questions: 
1) when you say: "but the analytical queries taking minutes long can theoretically lock your table for that long keeping the inserts waiting for a few minutes", is that true even for a 2 seconds query? Is the table locked for writing for the whole time and the writings are stopped? I'd like to learn about this behaviors, is there a place where I can find this kind of information/warnings?...

Comment: 2) About the in-memory tables, let's say I want to perform some analytics every minute on the last 72h data. I was even thinking on keeping that data as data objects in my application, and process them there. Then I thought of the in memory tables, but you also say that SQL keeps "regular data" in cache, how does it work? How is it supposed to know to keep in memory the last 72h only (not more, for not using too much memory, and not less, for not having to hit the disk)

Comment: "*is that true even for a 2 seconds query? Is the table locked for writing for the whole time and the writings are stopped?*" - It depends on the query & other factors but with the default (pessimistic concurrency) isolation level, if a read query causes a lock escalation on the entire table, then writing against that table is blocked for the entirety of that lock's duration during the execution of the read query, regardless if it's for 2 seconds or 2 days long. There might be some optimizations in the engine for insert-only use cases that I'm not aware of though. I'm not an expert on locking.

Comment: @MattiaDurli "*but you also say that SQL keeps "regular data" in cache, how does it work?*" - This one is too long to be answered in a comment unfortunately. You're welcome to ask a new question so a detailed response can be provided. The 5 second version of it is the data of a table is saved on disk in a structure called a "data page". Whenever a query is ran against a table, SQL Server locates the necessary data pages from the disk and loads them into Memory. Depending on the frequency of access and the Memory pressure on the server determines how long they stay cached in Memory.

Comment: "*I'd like to learn about this behaviors, is there a place where I can find this kind of information/warnings?*" - Asking more targeted questions on here (such as "*how does lock escalation work*" and "*are inserts affected by page and table level locks*") is probably a pretty good way to find more information. Otherwise there's a series of blogs out there you can find by Googling those topics (I don't have a specific article off the top of my head, sorry). But SQL.kiwi, RedGate, or anything by Aaron Bertrand, Paul White, Paul Randall, Kendra Little, Erik Darling, or Brent Ozar is good info.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!

Comment: @MattiaDurli No problem! Best of luck!

Comment: Fantastic answer and details here! If I could add just one more thing I would say beware of "premature optimisaion" and "overengineering". Table copies, in memory tables, special app caches etc. all these things are additional custom complexity which in most cases is unecessary, i.e. as mentioned, SQL keeps data in memory anyway (if you have enough), There are a lot of "inbuilt" features (like indexes, columnstore, snapshot isolation, read only replicas) that solve these problems with zero custom code. Once you've identified your specific problem that is :)